# how to print values in reverse order for this logic?

Tags: html, jsp

Here in my code i'm printing values 1 to 64.But i need to print those values in reverse order that is start from 64 to 1.And all values in single table.For my current logic values are printing in 2 tables.number 1 to 56 in first table and 57 to 64 in second table.How to change this logic.

```
<%
        int apps = 64;
        int N = 1, k;
        label:
        for (int i = 1; i <= apps; i++) {
            out.println("<table>");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                out.println("<tr>");
                for (k = N; k <= N + 7; k++) {
                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println("" + k + "");
                    out.println("</td>");
                    if (k == apps) {
                        break label;
                    }
                }
                out.println("</tr>");
                N = N + 8;
            }
            out.println("</table>");
        }
    %>
```

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out.println("<table>");
int row=8;
int col =8;

int count = 64;
for(int i = row;i>0 ;i--){
out.println("<tr>");
  for(int j=col;j>0;j--){
    out.println("<td>"+count+"</td>");
    count--;
  }
out.println("</tr>");
}

out.println("</table>");
```

Try this.

Comment: each values are printing in separate row.i need 8 values per row staring from 64.

Comment: prtk_shah,please run your code,it is not printing as per requirement.

Comment: @abdul sorry for the problem. This is final one.

Comment: Thank you its working fine.Is there way to write same logic without row and col variables because here we need to specify particularly how many rows and columns.Like what i have written in my original logic.

Comment: prtk_shah,i got it how to write logic without row and columns.

Comment: @abdul can you post it. because I've tried it but endup with some thing same as above. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifying rows and columns variable we can write it as follows:

```
 out.println("<table>");
        int apps = 64;
        double rowColumn = Math.sqrt(apps);
        for (double i = rowColumn; i > 0; i--) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            for (double j = rowColumn; j > 0; j--) {
                out.println("<td>" + apps + "</td>");
                apps--;
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
```

It will work fine.